# Catch IntegrityError in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Working with Django 1.4

I would like to catch an Integrity Error when a user does enter a duplicate value. At this moment the application just shows the default Django error page. (debug = True)

#### model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100, unique=True)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", related_name="children")
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name="foos")
```

#### admin

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import IntegrityError

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooForm

    search_fields = ['name']
    list_display = ['name']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        try:
            obj.save()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            raise ValidationError(e)
```

#### form

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields["parent"].queryset = Foo.objects.filter(bar=self.instance.bar)

    def clean(self):
        bar_identifier = self.cleaned_data.get("bar").identifier

        parent = self.cleaned_data.get("parent")
        if parent is not None:
            parent_bar_identifier = parent.bar.identifier
            if bar_identifier != parent_bar_identifier:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Bar identifier should match parent Bar identifier")

        return self.cleaded_data
```

At this moment I get an error page showing a ValidationError instead of an IntegrityError. (Which makes perfect sense)

How would I be able to properly catch the IntegrityError and show it at the top of the Django admin page?

## Update

I noticed there was a form in there to check if `foo.parent.bar.identifier` matches `foo.bar.identifier`.
When I remove the form from the ViewAdmin the error handling works as expected.

So I guess the question here would be: How do I check if the parents match when saving the admin form?

Comment: Can you show some code that reproduces the problem? The model form in the admin should validate the unique constraint and show an error message. The Django docs state that you shouldn't use [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) to do stuff like this.

Comment: You can use the `messages` framework (django.contrib.messages) to display notices at the top of admin page.

Comment: @Selcuk I have used the messages framework and now I get redirected to the list view with the error message at the top. However I also get a message the the object is saved.  When I look in the database the object has not been saved. A better solution would be to show the error message at the top of the item's admin page.

Comment: @Alasdair That was my first thought as well, but I do get the integrity error.

Comment: Then I think there's something in your code that you're not showing us. The example you are showing shouldn't raise `IntegrityError`. I'm pretty sure it's not a Django 1.4 issue.

Comment: Have you try `raise forms.ValidationError(e)` using modelform, not sure but hope it'll work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't try to handle this in the `save_model` method. The admin view expects the `save_model` method to succeed, so does not handle integrity or validation errors. If the `save_model` method is raising `IntegrityError`, then the problem is probably somewhere else.

I think your problem is that you have forgotten to call the parent class' `clean` method when you overrode it. This prevents the form from validating the unique field. See [the warning in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method) for more info.

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(FooForm, self).clean()
        parent = cleaned_data.get("parent")
        ...
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Or some june may write: on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING

```
some = models.ForeignKey(Some, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```